# Why @extend placholder only works on a specific element

Tags: css, sass

In scss I have the following code:

```
%cursor--pointer {
   cursor: pointer;
}

.drawer {
   &__item {
      @extend %cursor--pointer;
   }
}
```

Which should output:

```
.drawer__item {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

In HTML I have the following tags:

```
<a href="./" class="drawer__item"><span class="drawer__item__content">Home</span></a>

<div class="drawer__item"><span class="drawer__item__content">test</span></div>
```

Now I would expect that when hovering both show the pointer but the `div` doesn't. When looking in the dev tools the `cursor:pointer` isn't event there.

`div`:
[image: Div]

`a`:
[image]

The styling is there. It's just not getting applied:

[image]

The styles tab shows the following. In the styles tab the lines from the previous image can't be found.

[image]

So my question is why is the cursor set on the `a` tag but not on the `div`?
The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/SuperDJ/material/blob/master/src/sass/components/_drawer.scss#L59).

Comment: "a" tag has "cursor: pointer" by default, so I think that both of them doesn't use this property. Can you double check your sass and css file again? Did you include your css file correctly?

Comment: @KeivanSina Other styles are working just the cursor property isn't applied. Which can also be seen in the just added image

Comment: Can you show the Styles tab instead of the Computed tab?

Comment: @Ry- Have added an image of the styles tab and included a link to the repository.